# How do to configure Karma to NOT restart the browser when it is closed?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, karma-runner

I'm using the following command to run my unit tests in sort of a "debug" mode (where `--debug` is a custom key I added for my own purposes).

`karma start ./.config/karma.conf.js --browsers=Chrome --debug`

The command works fine -- it runs the tests and keeps it's instance of the Chrome browser open indefinitely. However, when I'm attempting to kill the browser by closing it, the test runner restarts it (up to 2 times).

```
05 01 2018 13:00:56.024:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome crashed.

05 01 2018 13:00:56.024:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout:
05 01 2018 13:00:56.024:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr:
05 01 2018 13:00:56.256:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
```

**Is there a way to instruct Karma to NOT restart Chrome when it's closed/crashed?**

Answer (score 1):

Set the `retryLimit` in your karma config to `-1`:

> ### retryLimit
>
> **Type:** Number
>
> **Default:** 2
>
> **Description:** When a browser crashes, karma will try to relaunch. This defines how many times karma should relaunch
>   a browser before giving up.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/docs/config/01-configuration-file.md#retrylimit